# The starter project for TypeScript with node/express endorsed by Microsoft does not have any classes?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

[Starter project](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter)

Why doesn't it use classes at all? I mean I understand there are types and therefore type-safety(courtesy TypeScript), but I see no usage of classes anywhere. 
Any particular reason for not using classes? I guess I'll have to create my own starter project with classes(coming from an OOD world). Are there any drawbacks to that?

Comment: Typescript does’t require using OOP. This example seems to just add types to the existing way of working with express. I agree it seems a bit counter intuitive, because they do use function closures in a semi-oop way. I think this is why express feels a bit outdated - this programming style was used widely before we had classes.

Comment: Because Express isn't OOP-oriented, and it doesn't make sense to use OOP for OOP's sake. Mongoose can make use of classes http://mongoosejs.com/docs/advanced_schemas.html , but they aren't necessary.

Comment: Well, with the type definitions for all the npm modules and Express 4, I think it would've been nice to see all TypeScript features(including classes) demo'd. But that's ok. Maybe it's for the users to explore that.

Comment: @alokarya It's not a demo. It's a starter project for real-world use. If you're after OO, consider checking NestJS. It's Express-based framework that heavily borrows from Angular and works best with TS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another starter project made similarly with Express and TypeScript. In addition, it embodies an Object Oriented implementation of Models, Services and Data Access Objects (DAO's) using Mongoose and Inversify:

https://github.com/omerg/express-mongodb-base

If you have a J2EE programming background with Spring MVC and Hibernate, the structure of the project should be very familiar.

There are some other paradigms that the project mention such as Containerization and CI/CD. Contributions are welcome! :)